# Nativescript 8 iOS device not recognized, but available in Xcode and the Finder

Tags: ios, nativescript, nativescript-cli

I am using Ventura 13.5, Xcode 15.0.1, NS version 8.6, physical iPhone 11 with iOS 16.7.2.  here is the output from ns doctor ios:

```
✔ Getting environment information 

No issues were detected.
✔ Xcode is installed and is configured properly.
✔ xcodeproj is installed and is configured properly.
✔ CocoaPods are installed.
✔ CocoaPods update is not required.
✔ CocoaPods are configured properly.
✔ Your current CocoaPods version is newer than 1.0.0.
✔ Python installed and configured correctly.
✔ The Python 'six' package is found.
✔ Xcode version 15.0.1 satisfies minimum required version 10.
✔ Getting NativeScript components versions information...
✔ Component nativescript has 8.6.1 version and is up to date.
```

When I run ns device ios I get

```
Searching for devices...

 Connected devices & emulators
Cannot find connected devices. Reconnect any connected devices, verify that your system recognizes them, and run this command again.
```

I can see the device in Xcode and the Finder, but not recognized by NS. I can also run the app from Xcode on my device.

I tried restarting the device, restarting the mac, disconnecting and reconnecting the device, clearing the trusted devices and trusting the mac again, but nothing seems to help.

Any ideas?